# Integral of the square of the exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix such that the real part of all eigenvalues are negative. It is well known that: 
$$ \int_0^\infty \exp(At)dt = -A^{-1}.$$
In other word, the element $(i,j)$ of the above matrix is $\int_0^\infty \exp(At)_{ij}dt = -A^{-1}_{ij}$.

Is it possible to simplify a similar expression where each element is squared: 
$$ \int_0^\infty (\exp(At)_{ij})^2 dt = ??$$

For one-dimensional matrices (a.k.a. real numbers), this is easy and we obtain $(-2A)^{-1}$ because $\exp(-at)^2=\exp(-2at)$. This does not work for $n\ge2$ and in this case the answer is not $(2A)^{-1}$.

I am wondering if it is possible to simplify the above expression.

Comment: are you sure the first equation is correct? It seems that it should be $\int\exp(-At)dt$.

Comment: I indeed forgot a "-A" in the right-hand side.

Comment: $\left[e^{tA}\right]^2=e^{2tA}$ as expected.

Comment: I know that $[e^{tA}]^2=e^{2tA}$. Yet, my computation involves the square of each element (not the element of the square).

Comment: X-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/q/255474/91764

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already been answered on MO http://mathoverflow.net/q/255474/91764